# How to extract video from multiple videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, extract, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

I want to extract video from multiple videos with ffmpeg. Normally, I could extract the video file from one large video file with the following command.

```
ffmpeg -ss 648 -t 29 -i /MatrixMovie.ts -f mpegts -pix_fmt yuv422p -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -map 0 snapshot.ts
```

But now I have 10 minutes of parts of this  video file (MatrixMovie_part1.ts, MatrixMovie_part2.ts etc) instead of one large file. And the video that I want to extract starts on one of these parts and ends on the other.

**My question** is How to extract video from multiple videos with ffmpeg?

I've been dealing with ffmpeq for days but couldn't manage it. I would appreciate it if you could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all parts virtually together in FFmpeg:

```
./ffmpeg -i file1.ts -i file2.ts -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -ss 00:04 -t 11 out.ts
```

Short explanation:
`-i <file>` is added for each source file you have

Now we need to concat all files together in one filter `-filter_complex`.
`[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]` defines all relevant inputs (first digit is the counter of the input file; v = video-stream, a = audio-stream; last digit 0 is to pick only one found stream. Add more `[x:v:0][x:a:0]` for each input file. The command `concat=n=2:v=1:a=1` tells FFmpeg how to deal with all this streams (n=2 because of 2 inputs; increase this number for each input file; v=1 for one video; a=1 for one audio output). `[outv][outa]` are output names of the filter.

`-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]"` maps the output of the filter for further processing.

Now you have one virtual video/audio. E.g. if you have 2 input files with a duration of 10 seconds, the virtual stream is now 20 seconds long.

`-ss 00:04 -t 11` you know already to seek and trim the video.